# css centering text within a background image

Tags: html, css

I have a number inside a background image. I can't put the number in the center of the circle. So far, I have center the number but it is in the topmost part of the circle. How do I move it down to the center?

HTML code:

```
<div class="number">
  <p>
  576
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.number{
    float:left;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:200%; 
    }

.number p{  
    position:relative;
    top: 38%;
    left:57%;
    z-index:999;    
    background-image: url("http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.png");
    width: 207px;
    height: 204px;
    }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ydz8cn7b/) is the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to set a `line-height` for your `p` element like `line-height: 204px;` which is equivalent to the element height.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ydz8cn7b/2/)

```
.number p {
    /* Other properties here */
    line-height: 204px; /* add this */
}
```

Also, I have no idea why you are using `top` and `left` properties here with `z-index` property, I think you can clean up the mess by a great extent.

Comment: what if the paragraph consists multiple lines?

Comment: @NileshMahajan That's not the case here.. I go according to the use case

Comment: Yeah, but don't you think that the solution should be scalable always. I just put my thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

check your fiddel now.https://jsfiddle.net/ydz8cn7b/1/

I have updated it as per your requirement:

**HTML**

```
<div class="number">
    <p>576</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.number {
    float:left;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:200%;
    display:table;
}
.number p {
    display:table-cell;
    background-image: url("http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.png");
    width: 207px;
    height: 204px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `line-height:` 204px

This option is suitable when the text consists of a single line

```css
.number{
 float:left;
 background-position: center;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:200%; 
 }
 
.number p{ 
 position:relative;
 top: 38%;
 left:57%;
 z-index:999; 
 background-image: url("http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.png");
 width: 207px;
 height: 204px;
    line-height: 204px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="number">
 <p>
    576
    </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the good solution is

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydz8cn7b/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below CSS properties inside this class `.number p{}`

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```